# How to fix JEdit 5.1.0 to don't complain about Java SE 6?

Tags: macos, java-7, jedit

I have Mac OS X 10.9 and Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)... I had another version of JEdit (I guess JEdit 4) and Java 6 before and my JEdit was working fine.

Then I upgraded Java to Java 7 because NetBeans7.4 needed to be installed with Java 7 (and I needed this new NetBeans because I had a fatal issue with NetBeans 7.3.1). So anyway, I installed Java 7 and I installed NetBeans 7.4 and my netbeans is working perfectly now, but when I tried to run the JEdit it brought up an alert saying it needs Java SE 6 to run!

I did some search in the net, and it seems that JEdit 4.5 (and I guess JEdit 5.1 too!) should not have any issue with Java 7, So I installed JEdit 5.1.0... I expected that it should work and don't bring up that complain alert BUT it didn't work and brought up "Java SE 6 is needed" complain again ...

I still can run JEdit using this command, but I can't use Cmd+C & Cmd+V shortcuts for copy and paste and it kills me!

```
java -jar /Applications/jEdit.app/Contents/Resources/Java/jedit.jar
```

Is there anybody who knows why JEdit 5.1 is complaining about Java 6 and how to fix it?! I really appreciate your help!

https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3615181&group_id=588&atid=100588

---

After almost 3 months struggling with jEdit I'm ready to give up... I still can't run jEdit like a normal app. What do you suggest to replace my jEdit?! The main feature I need is realtime access to the server files... Most of editors keep a local version of files, so they don't show the changes when they are made in the server side. for example when I switch to a new git branch on server, my netbeans is still showing the branch that I was working before switching, so I need to do a complete download on the project. Any idea?!

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set everywhere?  If you open a new shell and do `echo $JAVA_HOME`, does it point to the correct java installation?

Comment: yes, it does: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/

Comment: Does that directory have something like these directories?  `bin  db  include  jre  lib  man`

Comment: @RossRogers yes, it has all the directories and readme file and other stuffs... I really appreciate that you consider helping me, because I'm still stuck with this issue.

Comment: But it seems that it is not a java issue... I got connected to one of cool jEdit guys and he was sure that it is because of my os upgrade.

Comment: I hope he doesn't mind that I publish his words: "jedit.app doesn't work properly or find java7 in both cases. it is looking for java6 when java7 is installed already. The issue is with either the DMG installer, or the JEDIT.app that is created by the DMG installer. In both cases, we need to replace the DMG installer with another DMG or setup program that actually works with java7 and installs jEdit properly. I have 10.9 now also, so I understand that this same bug will manifest itself in different ways on different OSs/configurations."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Monica About one year later after your question, I've experienced the same issue with Mountain Lion (according to jEdit's homepage, 5.1.0 is still the current stable version).

I've installed jEdit in `/Applications/Dev/` (**not** `/Applications` as most people do, I believe; that's not important **except** for designating the path, *see below*). I'm using Java 7.

The following works for me from the command line, *like for you*:
`java -jar /Applications/Dev/jEdit.app/Contents/Resources/Java/jedit.jar`

So, I used Automator to create a normal MacOS Application named "MyJEdit.app" as in the screenshot. Now I can launch MyJEdit instead of jEdit. Other java flags might be required, for instance to set the memory usage (*cf* `java -help` and `java -X`).

[image: Automator screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the info! Hopefully it will help someone! I actually got exhausted of waiting and finally switched to Eclipse... Well it is not as good as jEdit for Perl programming, but well, I've got use to it now... and jEdit works for me on Yosemite, but it is a fresh install, so not sure could it still work if it was installed before the upgrade! anyway, thanks for your respond! :)

Answer (score 2):

jEdit on Mac OS X and Java 7 is a long story of annoyances, and fine points that Apple did not get quite right up to Java 6, and Oracle still learning about native platform support in the past 1-2 years.

Starting with Jdk-7u40 it works technically quite well, even Retina displays, but jEdit needs to be adapted slightly.

jEdit 5.2 will probably work with Java 7 out of the box, but a few points are still open.  See also the tracker item 3615000 at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3615000&group_id=588&atid=300588).

Here is a practical proof that it works: [Isabelle/jEdit](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/) -- it is an application based on jEdit that is bundled differently than official jEdit 5.1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your info! As soon as I read your comment that there is a new version of jEdit, I went and installed the last daily version of it (jedit5.2pre1install.jarjedit5.2pre1install.jar). It is working fine so far, I can use shortcuts now (that was such a terrible pain that didn't work)... I hope they will release jedit 5.2 soon! thanks again! :)